# When minimising page picture is over text

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to make a website; I change the width of the browser window, an image that I have on the page overlaps the text. How would I go about making the image just disappear instead?

CODE:

```css
<style>
 .contentAbout{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
 }

 #imageOne{
  height: 250px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 170px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  border: 3px outset white;
  
  
 }
</style>
```

```html
<div class = "contentAbout">
 <h2>About us</h2>
    <p> a paragraph</p>
</div>
<div class = "aboutImages">
 <img id = "imageOne" src = "http://i.imgur.com/6kbSaGL.png" alt = "Car"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With *css3* you can use a **Media Query** to hide an HTML element when the screen-width is changed.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Smoggs/epb2ouso/)

```css
.contentAbout {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
#imageOne {
  height: 250px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 170px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  border: 3px outset white;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  #imageOne {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="contentAbout">
  <h2>About us</h2>
  <p>a paragraph</p>
</div>
<div class="aboutImages">
  <img id="imageOne" src="http://i.imgur.com/6kbSaGL.png" alt="Car" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give values for the width and height of the page

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<div class="content_wrap">
  <div class = "contentAbout">
    <h2>About us</h2>
    <p> a paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <div class = "aboutImages">
    <img id = "imageOne" src = "http://i.imgur.com/6kbSaGL.png" alt = "Car"/>
  </div>
  <div class="clrb"></div>
</div>
<style>
    .aboutImages{
      float: left;
    }
    .contentAbout{
        float: left;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
        margin-top: -10px;
      }

    .clrb{
        clear:both;
    }

      #imageOne{
        height: 250px;
        margin-right: 170px;
        margin-top: -150px;
        border: 3px outset white;
      }
</style>
```